# Material-UI - Unable to click in multiline TextField inside Draggable Dialog

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a draggable dialog with a couple of text fields for a user to fill in and submit. However, when I set the multiline option on a TextField, I am no longer able to click in the field and type. I can only type inside the field if I tab into it. The TextFields that are not multiline work the way I want. How do I make it so that I can click and type into the multiline TextField???

A couple code snippets included here...
This is from the Draggable Dialog:

```
function PaperComponent(props) {
    return (
        <Draggable cancel="input">
            <Paper {...props} />
        </Draggable>
    );
}

const GenericDialog = props => {
return (
    <Dialog
        disableBackdropClick
        disableEscapeKeyDown
        disableRestoreFocus
        fullWidth={true}
        maxWidth={props.maxWidth}
        open={props.open}
        onClose={props.onClose}
        PaperComponent={PaperComponent}
    >
        <DialogTitle>{props.dialogTitle}</DialogTitle>
        {props.children}
            <DialogActions>
                <Button onClick={props.onSubmit} color="primary">
                    Submit
                </Button>
                <Button onClick={props.onClose} color="secondary" autoFocus>
                    Cancel
                </Button>
            </DialogActions>
        )}
    </Dialog>
```

This is how the text field that I am unable to click/type into is defined:

```
<TextField
    style={{ margin: 0, width: '350px' }}
    label="Task Description"
    helperText="(1024 character maximum)"
    inputProps={{ maxLength: 1024 }}
    multiline
    rows="4"
    onChange={this.handleChange('taskDescription')}
    value={this.state.task.taskDescription}
    variant="outlined"
/>
```

Comment: A [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing the problem would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My confusion was that I thought the TextField was an input. But with the multiline prop, it is instead a textarea. To resolve the problem, I changed the Draggable cancel prop to: cancel="input, textarea"

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextField
style={{ margin: 0, width: '350px' }}
label="Task Description"
helperText="(1024 character maximum)"
inputProps={{ maxLength: 1024 }}
multiline
rows="4"
autoFocus={true}
onChange={this.handleChange('taskDescription')}
value={this.state.task.taskDescription}
variant="outlined"/>
```